# MVC: OnDropDownChange call controller

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, model-view-controller, controller

I have this method on my controller

```
public JsonResult GetPlaceImageUrls(int? id)
{
     string[] urls = PlaceService.
                      GetByID(id, "Images").
                      Images.Select(i => i.URL).
                      ToArray();
     return Json(urls.First(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

And I am sure that it returns the data I want. I put onchange = "OnPlaceChange()" on my dropdown and I am also sure the onchange event is getting fired. However what I want to do is this:

```
@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
<script type="text/javascript">

    function OnPlaceChange() {
        var pid = document.getElementById("s_place").value;
        $.ajax({
            url: "admin/BlogEntries/GetPlaceImageUrls/" + pid,
            type: "GET",
            dataType: JSON,
            success: function (data) {
                window.alert(data);
            }
        });
    }

</script> 
}
```

But this does not work. I put a breakpoint on the controller but it does not get hit. Any ideas? Regards.

**UPDATE**

```
url: "/GetPlaceImageUrls/" + pid,
```

changing the ajax url solved the non hit breakpoint issue. However now, the success function does not work.

Comment: Hit F12 and see network traffic you might find what is wrong

Comment: thanks for your advice. I found the problem. But now the success function does not hit.

Answer (score 0):

First the problem was the ajax URL, and the solution was included in the question. The main problem of success function was not getting was it was thinking the data as JSON since I added "dataType: JSON" on ajax. However my controller method is returning an array of strings. So deleting dataType:JSON solved my problem. I believe "dataType: text" would do the same trick.